# firebird 3 identity column - return last inserted id

Tags: firebird, delphi

I am using FireDAC in Delphi 101. Berlin and I want to get the last inserted id of `IDENTITY DATA TYPE` column after executing insert query but, the returned value is **empty**.

Query: `INSERT INTO ACC_ACCOUNT_HEAD (ACCOUNT_HEAD_TITLE) VALUES ('TEST') returning ACCOUNT_HEAD_ID;`

table structure

```
CREATE TABLE ACC_ACCOUNT_HEAD (
 ACCOUNT_HEAD_ID       INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  ACCOUNT_HEAD_TITLE    VARCHAR(208),
  PRIMARY KEY (ACCOUNT_HEAD_ID)
);
```

**Note:** I know it is possible with [generators](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq243/) but I want to know if it is possible with `IDENTITY` column.

Complete Delphi Code:

```
var
aQry : TFDQuery;
begin
aQry := TFDQuery.Create(Self);
aQry.Connection := frmMain.aCon;

 aQry.SQL.Text :=
      'INSERT INTO ACC_ACCOUNT_HEAD (ACCOUNT_HEAD_TITLE) VALUES (:P1) returning ACCOUNT_HEAD_ID';
    aQry.ParamByName('P1').AsString := 'Testing';
    aQry.ExecSQL; // or Should I use aQry.Open(); to get returned value???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Delphi docs](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ADODB_TADOQuery_ExecSQL.html) about ExecSQL. (Bold is mine)

> ExecSQL returns an integer value reflecting **the number of rows affected** by the executed SQL statement.

I'm mostly a CBuilder++ (old) user, but you can try by using:

```
aQry.Open();
result := aQry.Fields[0].AsInteger;
aQry.Close();
```

And let me suggest to enclose the query inside a try-catch block.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Just looked into this page and helped me. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/RETURNING_Unified_Support_(FireDAC).